# permuting parameters

Tags: machine-learning, parameter-estimation

[image]

The above equation is the marginal likelihood, integrating over $c$:

In this case, I found that this model has $(784+1)K$ of parameters but how many ways can we permute the parameters of the model ($θ$ and $π$) and get the same marginal likelihood $p(x|θ)$?

Comment: Do you mean "summing" in stead of "integrating"?

Comment: thank you for your comment, I mean "summing" @Lovsovs

Comment: Great, you can edit your question accordingly by pressing the little "edit" at the bottom of your question.

Comment: @Lovsovs do you know how many ways can we permute the parameters of the model ? and get the same marginal likelihood?